# Visualise EC2 metadata with Prometheus and Grafana

Tags: amazon-web-services, prometheus, grafana

I want to monitor my AWS resources, typically EC2. I have a use case where I want to visualize EC2 instances on a dashboard which gives me data like total number of instances running in my account, their instance types, AZ, regions in which they are running, etc. I am looking for AWS inventory kind of tool which gives me details of only EC2.

I already have a Prometheus server and Grafana running in my setup. Is there a way I can push the EC2 metadata to Prometheus and visualize it via Grafana? If yes, how can I achieve this?

Comment: AWS Cloudwatch? (but it's not free)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can monitor compute resources in AWS such as EC2, ElasticBeanstalk, ECS and so on.
For instance, you can choose one of following options to monitor EC2 based on your need:

- Install data source such as Prometheus on EC2 and import to Grafana Dashboard
- Use AWS CloudWatch as data source then import to Grafana Dashboard. Please not that you have to install CloudWatch Agent on EC2 if you want to monitor custom metrics. See here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/metrics-collected-by-CloudWatch-agent.html for more detailed metrics that you can explore.

Below resource might be helpful for you:

- https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/617
- https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/aws-cloudwatch/